# how to use await async Task in for loop using c#?

Tags: c#, async-await, bots, telegram

I have created an API for sending  multiple videos in the same time like daily send 10-10 videos on the telegram bot. And I have created the API using **async task**.

I have put **await** in the loop but at that time I am getting the error "**Request timed out**".

Please tell me how can I use await in the loop?

Below is the code I used.

```
public async Task SendCasesOnTelegramBot()
{             
     DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Setting.ConnectionString(), "GetPostForTelegramBot");
  if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string VideoUrl = null;
        VideoUrl = MediaPath + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Url"].ToString();        
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("abc");                                   

          await Bot.SendVideoAsync("@abc", video: VideoUrl, caption: sb.ToString()); 
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: `Request timeout` seems to be a network/server related error. I don't think it's async/await related.

Comment: my pc is fully network under and please check my code it's that correct? using await?

Comment: @Stefan i want put some delay time in the for loop so how can do that?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(delayInMs);`

Comment: The code seems to be in order; How big are the files?

Comment: where is put this line in my code? and (delayInMs) mean in second??

Comment: my videos must 5mb.6 mb, 16mb like so that time i can't upload all the video on bot so i need set delay some time in the loop

Comment: You place it where you want to have the delay, perhaps above the `SendVideoAsync`. The delay is in milliseconds.

Comment: @Stefan i am put await Task.Delay(180000); this line and i am go run utility and in my ds length up to 10+ videos so that time just go there only 2 o 3 videos and my utility is stop so that time it's code is ok in the for loop using await or i need to change some in the code? can you give me hint some

Comment: The hint is: `await Bot.SendVideoAsync` returns only after the upload is done. The delay is not necessary, `Request timeout` is a timeout on the recipient's side. You might want to start with a single file first.

Comment: @Stefan i have try also with single file is working very well

Comment: Try your largest file.

Comment: yes i am try with 16mb size of videos and working well but i am doing work with loop and send 10 or 10+ videos then just go there 2 or 3 videos so i want fix this issue.

Comment: `Request timed out` is a server related error. Please check the documentation of telegram to see if there are any restrictions imposed.

Comment: ok i will check i am not getting any error just i want to send more videos same time on bot